# Using for loops to group one variable by another variable and assign output to a vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame with information about solar panel installations. Important variables are id, yearBuilt, kw, and panels. A simplified version would look like this:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
yearBuilt <- c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012)
kw <- c(20, 35, 10, 100, 10)
panels <- c(2, 3, 1, 8, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(id, yearBuilt, kw, panels)
```

I want to create a new data frame that has the sum of kw and panels by year.

To create this data frame, I figured I would create the three vectors (years; sum of kw by year, which I'll call kwSum; and sum of panels by year, which I'll call panelsSum) and then join them with data.frame. I created the years vector with

```
years <- sort(unique(df1$yearBuilt))
```

To get the kwSum vector, I tried the following:

```
kwSum <- c()
for(i in 1:length(years)) {
    kwSum[i] <- 0        
            for(j in 1:nrow(df1)) {
                    if(df1$yearBuilt[j] == i){
                            kwSum[i] <- kwSum[i] + df1$kw[j]
                    }
            }
```

}

However, this creates a vector of 0's. Removing the kwSum[i] <- 0 part doesn't help. The vector is the right length, but my inner for loop doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

I realize that lapply might help in this situation, but I'm curious how I could accomplish this with simple for loops, as I'm still trying to nail down the basics.

Comment: `df1$yearBuilt[j] == i` --> `df1$yearBuilt[j] == years[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `aggregate()` to group by variables and aggregate columns, no `for` loops needed:

```
aggdf <- aggregate(. ~ yearBuilt, df1[c("yearBuilt", "kw", "panels")], FUN=sum)
aggdf

#   yearBuilt  kw panels
# 1      2010  55      5
# 2      2011 110      9
# 3      2012  10      1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(yearBuilt) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(sum), kw:panels)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# yearBuilt    kw panels
#      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      2010    55      5
#2      2011   110      9
#3      2012    10      1
```